# C- number checking function gives infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, int, infinite

I'm trying to write a small function that will get a number.
The function should be idiot-proof so it would give warnings if ie. someone entered a character instead.

I wrote a function like the one below, but if I enter a non-int the program gives me an infinite loop, constantly repeating the printf "Not a valid number" so I never get a chance to do the correct input.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int ret = 0; ret < 1;)
    {
        int num;

        printf("\n Please input a number: ");
        ret = scanf ("%d", &num);
        if (ret < 1)
            printf ("\nNot a valid number!");
        else
            printf("\nYou input %d", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `(y = 0)` -> `(y == 0)` simple typo

Comment: Please sort out the indentation of the code

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, you should not suffer with this silly mistakes.

Comment: "The function should be idiot-proof" – so then stop using `scanf()`. The mere existence of a call to `scanf()` in your code means that you're not aware of its shortcomings, and consequently your code cannot be idiot-proof.

Comment: What is the `'A'` in `while ('A')` supposed to do?

Comment: Actually, the y=0 typo is a bug but its not the problem. The infinite loop without scanf blocking occurs for a different reason as I explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the line below with the comment about eating the input buffer. Since your scanf didn't find what it is looking for in the input buffer, the wrong input just stays there and fails forever unless you do something to "eat" it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    while ('A')
    {
        int x, y;
        printf("\n x: ");

        y = scanf ("%d", &x);
        printf("\nx = %d", x);
        if (y < 1)
        { // eat the input buffer so we can try again
            while ( getchar() != '\n' );
            printf ("\nWRONG!");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You edit the question to change the `while` into a `for`, but your answer uses a `while`: could you please have it consistent between the two posts?

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line `if (y = 0)` with this `if (y == 0)`.

Comment: This solution fixes a bug but not the problem. The problem is that all the scanf-s after the first one will return immediately (without blocking on new input) if the user inputs texts instead of a number. That's why the question is about an infinite number of printouts not simply an incorrect printout.